# How can I update an onBeforeRequest event listener in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension with the following event listener in the background page...

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details){
        if ( ... details.url is in ArrayOfURLs ...  ){
            ... do stuff ...
        }
    }, {
        urls:  ["<all_urls>"],
        types: ["main_frame"]
    }, ["blocking"]
);
```

What I want to do is pass the array of urls to the event listener in the first place. So it should look like this...

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details){
        ... do stuff ...
    }, {
        urls:  ArrayOfURLs,
        types: ["main_frame"]
    }, ["blocking"]
);
```

Is there a way I can update the event listener when I add/remove items from the ArrayOfURLs array?

Comment: I think the section on rules and the dynamically assigning them might be of interest to you: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events

Comment: @gpgekko The number of actions the rule system can invoke is extremely limited. `declarativeWebRequest` API providing needed actions is not in Stable and there's no timeline on making it available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common practice is to remove the old handler and add a new one.

```
function requestHandler(details){
  /* ... do stuff ... */
}

function setListener(ArrayOfURLs) {
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(requestHandler);
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    requestHandler,
    { urls: ArrayOfURLs, types: ["main_frame"] },
    ["blocking"]
  );
  chrome.webRequest.handlerBehaviorChanged();
}
```

The last call is needed, since Chrome caches the rules, but it's [very expensive in terms of performance](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#method-handlerBehaviorChanged).

Comment: That's great, it won't be called often so should be fine. Thanks